# Unable to generate rails footnote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I am trying to install debug tool called rails-footnotes on Rails 3.0 following instruction on [GitHub](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes). A check running bundle show rails-footnotes show that I got rails-footnotes-3.7.4 installed. However, when I run

```
rails generate rails_footnotese:install
>>Could not find generator rails_footnotese:install.
```

I hope someone experienced the same issue might help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the version from git? According to the history there was a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.7.4 doesn't use a generator, only the newer 3.7.5 (which hasn't been released yet) does. Also, the README has a typo; it should be `rails_footnotes:install`, not `rails_footnotese:install` (there is already a pull request to fix this).

If you want to stay on the stable 3.7.4, all the generator command does is add the `config/initializers/rails_footnotes.rb` file with the same content from the README:

```
if defined?(Footnotes) && Rails.env.development?
  Footnotes.run! # first of all

  # ... other init code
end
```

and a `.rails_footnotes` file with this:

```
#this code temporarily disables notes for all controllers
# Footnotes::Filter.notes = []
```

Otherwise, use the git version to make the generator work:

```
gem 'rails-footnotes', :git => "git://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes.git"
```